# Where in SpringHow in Spring Boot do I solve a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/context/MappingContext"?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, classnotfoundexception

I"m using Java 8 and Spring Boot.  Trying to build a simple REST application that sits on a MongoDB.  I have this in my Gradle build file

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.1.5.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.5.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.5.RELEASE'
}
```

but when I go to start my app I get an error about not being able to find a class, "org/springframework/data/mapping/context/MappingContext":

```
localhost:todoapp-backend davea$ java -jar ./build/libs/spring-data-mongodb-example-1.0.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/context/MappingContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

What other dependency I'm I supposed to include to get the missing class found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Springboot Gradle plugin. It will solve all your dependecies issues .

```
plugins {
    id 'java
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.5.RELEASE'
}
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

}